# Integrate Facebook messenger into CRM without bot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

we have built a very simple bot that simply passes any message onto our own application. (we want to answer questions asked from our customers to be handled straight from our CRM application for customer service purpose)

Now, the bot is declined with message:

> Thank you for your submission. We tested the messenger experience on your associated page and received either no response from your messenger bot or received a human response. Please resubmit with the new, improved version of your bot.

Which raises the question for me: is it even allowed to do human assistance via the messenger API? Or is it bot only? I have read through all the platform policies, use case examples, etc.

So, how do I create the simplest integration? (send message straight through to one of our customer service users?)

Comment: I don’t think it makes sense to use a messenger bot for this in the first place. You should rather go via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/conversations

Comment: Hi, we would really like to use this API, but as far as we know there is no way to use to post messages anymore as it has been deprecated since graph api 2.5

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/conversation/messages

We can only use the graph API to read (old) messages, but not post new ones.

Comment: Reading page messages via `/{conversation-id}/messages` still seems to work fine in Graph API Explorer, using API version 2.6 – so I’d assume answering them should still work as well. The changelog mentions nothing about this being deprecated either, as far as I can see. (After the v2.6 rollout, a lot of documentation pages had problems with wrong _“This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v2.x”_ notes appearing.)

Comment: `/{conversation-id}/messages` has the following at the top of the page: This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v2.5.
I don't think it works.

Comment: Yes, it was deprecated indeed. We will try in the next week to use the functions, but I do not think the Graph API is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Making a bot is easy if you use [Wit.ai](https://wit.ai) which is an NLP and speech API. It can integrate with the messenger/graph API. Basically, you send text to wit.ai and it returns the intent. For example: you send "get me a large pizza" to Wit and it returns something like (intent = pizza, size=large, time = now) You could also try api.ai but in my opinion, it is not as good yet.